# Creating master and slaves DNS with puppet module camptocamp bind

Tags: linux, dns, puppet

Trying to create a master and slave (redundancy) DNS with puppet module camptocamp bind. In slave profile, I've set **transfer_source => '192.168.1.20'** to masters ip: 192.168.1.20. It should then synchronize and copy dns records from master to the slave.

But I got complaints about that it could only be set to slave zones. I've followed the README from puppet forge for the module: https://forge.puppet.com/camptocamp/bind/readme

**dnsmaster.pp**

```
class profile::dnsbind::server {

include 'bind'

bind::zone {'example.com':
  ensure       => 'present',
  zone_contact => 'contact.example.com',
  zone_ns      => ['ns0.example.com'],
  zone_serial  => '2012112901',
  zone_ttl     => '604800',
  zone_origin  => 'example.com',
}

bind::a { 'example.com':
  ensure    => 'present',
  zone      => 'example.com',
  ptr       => false,
  hash_data => {
    'host1' => { owner => '192.168.0.1', },
    'host2' => { owner => '192.168.0.2', },
  },
}
}
```

**dnsslave.pp**

```
class profile::dnsbind::server_slave {

include 'bind'

bind::zone {'example.com':
  ensure       => 'present',
  zone_contact => 'contact.example.com',
  zone_ns      => ['ns0.example.com'],
  zone_serial  => '2012112901',
  zone_ttl     => '604800',
  zone_origin  => 'example.com',
  transfer_source => '192.168.1.20', 
}
}
```

**The error message:**

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Zone 'example.com': transfer_source can be set only for slave zones! at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/bind/manifests/zone.pp:80:5 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/profile_dns2.pp:5 on node centos7-3
    Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
    Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Answer (score 1):

> It should then synchronize and copy dns records from master to the
>   slave.
>
> But I got complaints about that it could only be set to slave zones.

Evidently, the module does not recognize that you're trying to configure a slave zone.  How do you suppose it would know?  Well, apparently not from the presence of a `transfer_source` property.

> I've followed the README from puppet forge for the module:
>   https://forge.puppet.com/camptocamp/bind/readme

I'll believe that you started by pulling the example zone definition (for a master zone) from the readme, and I grant you that this module's docs are kinda shoddy.  But do nevertheless consider actually reading the docs thoroughly, not just skimming them.  If you had done, you would have found documentation for the `zone_type` parameter immediately following the the documentation for the `transfer_source` parameter:

> $zone_type = master
>
> Specify if the zone is master/slave/forward.

Use this to specify that you're configuring a slave zone.

Comment: Thanks John for your help so far, I've edited the question since there was a problem that followed when adding parameters you suggested which actually solved the first problem but then other problem emerged.

Comment: If you have a new question then present it as one.  It is not acceptable here to modify a question  you have already posted into a different one, *especially* after having received an answer.  Accordingly, I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: Alright, wasn't sure if I should edit or ask new question. There was a popup when I was going to comment about it if I was sure I dont want to edit the question instead. But I started a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791991/creating-master-and-slaves-dns-with-puppet-module-camptocamp-results-not-showin)